# Angular2: How can I have a parent component tell a child what size to be?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working in Angular 2.  I have a component - chord-graph - that I want to display at various sizes depending on what parent component it's included in.

I have a detail-display where I want the chord-graph component to be height: 500px and width: 700px.

I have a dashboard-display where I want the chord-graph component to be height: 200px and width: 300px.

I've attempted to do this by passing the dimensions to the chord-graph using @Input.

chord-graph.component.ts:

```
export class ChordGraphComponent {
    @Input() dimensions: {height: number, width: number};
}
```

chord-graph.component.html:

```
<div #container [ngStyle]="{ 'height.px': dimensions.height, 'width.px': dimensions.width }"></div>
```

detail-view.component.ts:

```
export class DetailViewComponent {
    dimensions: { height: number, width: number} = {height: 500, width: 700};
}
```

detail-view.component.html:

```
<chord-graph [dimensions]=dimensions></chord-graph>
```

dashboard-view.component.ts:

```
export class DashboardViewComponent {
    dimensions: { height: number, width: number} = {height: 200, width: 300};
}
```

dashboard-view.component.html:

```
<chord-graph [dimensions]=dimensions></chord-graph>
```

This currently throws a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ChordGraphComponent0.detectChangesInteral`.  If I set the height/width to a number in chord-graph.component.html then the page loads with the element at that size.

Comment: Try changing your chord-graph.component.html to `<div #container [ngStyle]="{ 'height.px': dimensions?.height, 'width.px': dimensions?.width }"></div>` The component may be trying to set the height/width before dimensions is defined

Comment: Why using [dimensions]=dimensions, mean to say without any quote, property should be used in quote, is not that true??

Comment: I have created a plunker example satisfying to your question and everything worked as expected. Please take a look at this plunk: https://embed.plnkr.co/HNdP93kZYvl7UGJkwX4M/ maybe I have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably skip styling with attributes and style only with css. Each parent can set the common child style via :

```
 :host ::ng-deep chord-graph{
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `<div #container [ngStyle]="{ 'height.px': dimensions?.height, 'width.px': dimensions?.width }"></div>`expression operator (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-operators) should help.

Also it's good to have default values for @Input properties.